# how to use stringr package function str_subset to subset rows in a data table

Tags: r

Consider the below data table CM

```r
CM<-read.table(header=TRUE,
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
 text ="
subject cmdecod
001 CARBAMAZEPINE
001 DOXORUBICIN
001 CARBAZINE
001 VINCRISTINE
002 PILSICAINIDE
002 PHENOBARBITAL
002 BUTALBITAL
002 RIFAP"
 )
```

I want to subset this on `cmdecod='RIFAP'` using the `str_subset()`. Please help me.

I tried `str_detect()` as below, not sure why str_subset does not wok here

```r
CM2 <- filter(CM,str_detect(cmdecod, "RIFAP"))
CM2
```

Answer (score 2):

`str_subset` doesn't return a logical vector.  It just extracts the subset.  According to `?str_subset`

> str_subset() is a wrapper around x[str_detect(x, pattern)], and is equivalent to grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE)

whereas `filter` expects a logical vector to filter the rows

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(CM$cmdecod, "RIFAP"))
[1] "RIFAP"
```

Thus, it is used a way to subset a vector of values from the original vector.  The "RIFAP" is an actual input in the original vector and thus it got subsetted

```
CM$cmdecod
[1] "CARBAMAZEPINE" "DOXORUBICIN"   "CARBAZINE"     "VINCRISTINE"  
[5] "PILSICAINIDE"  "PHENOBARBITAL" "BUTALBITAL"    "RIFAP"
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the great answer of akrun here some more information:

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(CM$cmdecod, "RIFAP")
```

`str_subset` is a wrapper around:

```
CM$cmdecod[str_detect(CM$cmdecod, "RIFAP")]
```

and is equivalent to:

```
grep("RIFAP", CM$cmdecod, value=TRUE)
```

https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_subset.html